# Reaches code, doesn't execute and exits without error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

All my code works fine up to this point:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebPortalLogging
{
    public static class EventLogging
    {
    public static void LogEvent(string origin, string message, EventLogEntryType eventLogEntryType, int eventId)
        {
      const string source = "Software";
            const string log = "Application";

            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source))
                 EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, log);
      EventLog.WriteEntry(source, message, eventLogEntryType, eventId);      
        }
    }
}
```

I even use this class in another project and it works fine.  When it hits this line:

if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source)) 
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, log);

It hits this line and exits.

Here is what is in my output:

```
The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x28c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x470) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'VmBackup.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Google Drive\Code\VMBackup\VMBackup\bin\Debug\VmBackup.exe', Symbols loaded.
'VmBackup.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Google Drive\Code\VMBackup\VMBackup\bin\Debug\WebPortalLogging.dll', Symbols loaded.
The thread '<No Name>' (0xa44) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'VmBackup.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread '<No Name>' (0x107c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1838) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0xa78) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x10e0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6436] VmBackup.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6436] VmBackup.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

It doesn't reach the EventLog.WriteEntry. It is not outputting to the event log either.  I've restarted VS2010 and that didn't help. I have prompt at all errors turned on.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly I would use braces round your conditional as it is a little unclear if EventLog should Write the entry if EventLog doesnt have a Source.

```
if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source)) 
{
   EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, log); 
}

  EventLog.WriteEntry(source, message, eventLogEntryType, eventId);
```

Also try and wrap it in an `try/catch` block to see if you get any unhandled exception which is causing the program to randomly exit.

```
try {

     if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source)) 
     {
           EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, log);
     }

     EventLog.WriteEntry(source, message, eventLogEntryType, eventId);  

} catch (Exception e)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(e);
  }
```

Additional: The thread `'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x28c) has exited with code 0 (0x0)`.
The thread `'vshost.LoadReference' (0x470) has exited with code 0 (0x0)`. are not errors. Visual Studio is telling you that a background thread has exited. 0 indicates the thread ran successfully.

Comment: +1 for braces.  Braceless if statements are right up there with unformatted sql on my list of pet peeves.

Comment: I did both and it made no difference. I'm not catching an error. I am exiting on the line "if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source))" and it's not going any further.

Comment: This helped me with your "Additonal" about thread. I realized this was being called on a seperate thread and was exiting the thread before it finished. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect it is trying to create the eventLog Source and throwing an exception because that requires admin rights.