# While loop not working as intended in Pong game

Tags: c#, pong

I am attempting to create a Pong game in C# with Visual C# Express 2010.
For the most part, I have the main idea of the game finished, however I have an issue with the ball moving. I have create a for loop, like this:

```
public void ballSet()
{
    if (!Values.isPaused)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if (Values.totalTime.Elapsed.Seconds > 1)
            {
                Values.totalTime.Restart();
                ballMove(50, 50);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void ballMove(int factorX, int factorY)
{
    Values.ballLastX = ball.Location.X;
    Values.ballLastY = ball.Location.Y;  
    this.ball.Location = new Point(this.ball.Location.X + factorX, this.ball.Location.Y + factorY);
}
```

The "ballMove(50, 50);" is just for testing purposes at the moment. The issue is that when ballSet() is called, the form seems to close with a code of 0, meaning that there was no error.
I call ballSet() over here.

```
public Pong()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ballSet();
    Values.totalTime.Start();
}
```

I have already checked and the program does somewhat work when I remove the while loop in ballSet(), as well as the if statement checking the stopwatch (Values.totalTime is a Stopwatch). Obviously since the while loop is commented out, ballMove() is only called once, and the the ball moves once and stops.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I want the ball to be moving constantly, while still having it possible to perform other tasks such as moving the bat in Pong.

This is the output I can give you while running Pong.

http://pastebin.com/nj1pdg3U

Comment: Looks like you start the timer after you call ballset. If you don't start it in the initialize function it might be null.

Comment: starting the timer before calling ballSet() doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at your code, the while loop will never end. I know that's not your reported behaviour, but try swapping `ballSet()` and `Values.totalTime.Start();` around.

Like so:

```
 Values.totalTime.Start();
 ballSet();
```

This is because (in theory) the call to ballSet() will wait for a return, and the totalTime counter will never start, therefore never entering your IF block in the loop.

Comment: Pong() now reads this:                                                 public Pong()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Values.totalTime.Start();
            ballSet();
        }                                                                                                 I get this output when debugging, however:  The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x1b74) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in at the start of the code, and use `F10` to step through it, to see which line causes the code to exit.

Comment: Not sure what you meant, but I added a "break;" at the start of the while loop. The program loads fine, but the loop doesn't run. I put the break at the end of the while loop, and obviously the ball only moved once. Without the break, the step-through ends at "Application.Run(new Pong());" in Program.cs.

Comment: I meant a `breakpoint` not a `break`. Have you debugged C# code before? It's quite a good technique to learn, assuming you are in Visual Studio try this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: Weird. I went ahead to debug the program. I basically created a break point on the loop, and went ahead and step into the program. While spamming F11 to step into the next line of code, the program simply followed the loop as I had wanted. The Debugger moves through the loop over and over again, and it does not seem to stop. However, when I simply hit F5 to start debugging, the form never opens, and I still get the exit code 0.

Comment: That's a good start to figure out what is happening. If you remove the `ballSet()` function call, does the form remain on the screen, or does it exit with code zero? Might give you some clues about how you are creating the Form.

Comment: Upon commenting out ballSet(), the form operates perfectly, just without the ball moving obviously. I'm thinking that the infinite while loop is causing a crash. Maybe I should attempt to use tasks to move the ball.

Comment: Nice, good progress. How about dissecting the problem a little further? Add the call to `ballSet()` back in, but remove the call to `ballMove()`. Good test for your theory.

Comment: Thanks for helping me thus far by the way. I commented out the call for ballMove(), and I had the same issue with the call not commented out. At this point, I'm about 90% sure that the while loop is the problem here. Just out of curiosity, I changed to a for(;;) loop, and got all of the same results. I'm going to see what else I can find.

Comment: No problem, happy to assist! Interesting results. I would try just a while loop, with a basic sleep - removing ALL other code. Something like:`while(true) { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); }` thus proving the loop to be at fault.

Comment: Hm, same thing. I still receive the "The thread '<No Name>' (0xb84) has exited with code 0 (0x0)." I tried the while loop empty, and was given two thread exits in the output: "The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0xf78) has exited with code 0 (0x0)." and "The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x1984) has exited with code 0 (0x0)." Plus the no name thread exiting with code 0 again. I'm pretty sure we can safely say that the while loop is either conflicting with another function, or I have a different internal issue affecting the loop.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12803640/reaches-code-doesnt-execute-and-exits-without-error He recommends trying a `try catch`. Some other clues there in the accepted answer.